# How can I efficiently access the previous (or next) record given a Mongo cursor

Tags: meteor

I have a chat application.  Messages are stored in a Mongo collection with the following fields:

```
# Messages
#   body: string
#   nick: string
#   room_name: string
#   timestamp: timestamp
```

When I render a chat room, I want to apply a special style to a message if it follows a message by the same user.  But if I use the standard template iterator (this is CoffeeScript):

```
Template.messages.helpers
    messages: -> model.Messages.find()
    isFollowUp: -> /* some code here? */ false
```

And in the template (simplified):

```
{{#each messages}}<p class-"{{isFollowUp}}">{{nick}}: {{body}}</p>{{/each}}
```

Then inside the `isFollowUp` helper I can get access to the *current* message, but not the previous message.  Ideally I'd be able to do something like:

```
isFollowUp: -> if this.nick == this.previous().nick then "followup" else ""
```

**Important**: there are a lot of messages on the page, I can't afford to rerender the entire page every time a new message arrives.  There is a trivial solution like:

```
messages: -> model.Messages.find().fetch().map (v,i,a) ->
  prev: a[i-1]
  curr: v
  next: a[i+1]
```

But this erases the special `{{#each}}` dependency in Blaze (by passing an array instead of a Cursor to the template) and so forces re-render of the entire page whenever a new message arrives.

**The solution I'm looking for must avoid rerendering all messages**.  When a new message arrives, only that message and the message before it should be re-rendered.

Comment: In `isFollowUp` you can access the previous message with a selector using `this.timestamp` (I presume the messages are sorted by this field), but you may find that to clumsy?

Comment: Will it actually do the right thing with dependencies?  That is, I want to be sure that the rendered html for chat message #N depends only on message #N and #N-1, and that these dependencies are as lightweight as possible.  Adding an entirely new dependent `model.Messages.find()` for every row in chat seems like it could kill performance.

Comment: I'm afraid that you need to use a `model.Messages.find` to retrieve the previous message in a reactive way. But do you really need reactivity for this? Can messages be removed or changed? If messages only can be added, you don't need to access the previous message in a reactive way.